# How to apply css "font" Property values like caption|icon|menu... etc

Tags: css, fonts, shorthand

Here is the syntax:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

I am not sure how to apply, tried these variations but no luck:

```css
font: italic bold 12px/30px Arial icon
font: italic bold 12px/30px Arial|icon
font: italic bold 12px/30px icon
```

It work only if I apply this way:

```css
font: icon
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) you can find doc I referred

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's font-family or system name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

Answer (score 1):

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

This above means that what you can do is set a `font` shorthand, but those `caption` |`icon`(etc..) are a `font-family` type, therefore replace it -  in your example -  on `Arial`

```css
.p1 {
  font: italic bold 12px/30px icon
}

.p2 {
  font: italic bold 12px/30px Arial
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">FOO BAR</p>
<p class="p2">FOO BAR</p>
```